# string having doublequotes in between apart from the enclosing quotes

Tags: text-processing

I have a requirement.

My CSV file has a string `"Testurteil "sehr gut""` and I need to load this file (into `redis`) without removing the quotes, *or* I want it this way: `Testurteil "sehr gut"`, even if it has the closing quotes it's fine.

Comment: `csv` meant `comma separated values` in the first place, so `17,abc,Testurteil "sehr gut",08/15` is a valid line. Other options are `'Testurteil "sehr gut"'` or `"Testurteil ""sehr gut"""`.

Comment: You want to "load" it into what? Using what language? Do you just want to remove the quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
perl -pi.back -le 's/"(?:[^"]|"(?=[^,]))*"|[^",]*/($r=$&)=~
  s@(^"|"$|\\.)|"@$1||"\\\""@ge;$r/ge' file.csv
```

That uses heuristics to try and identify those double quote characters that are not the enclosing ones and escape them with a backslash.

For instance, it would change:

```
 "asd","","a,b"c,d"e,f",""",,blah
```

To:

```
 "asd","","a,b\"c,d\"e,f","\"",,blah
```

(leaving the original as `file.csv.back`)

To change them to single quotes instead of escaping them:

```
perl -pi.back -le 's/"(?:[^"]|"(?=[^,]))*"|[^",]*/($r=$&)=~
  s@(^"|"$|\\.)|"@$1||"'\''"@ge;$r/ge' file.csv
```

Comment: @BernieReiter - your edit to this answer was deleted, in the future if you have a follow up question, it's best to start it as a new question, not to edit the Q & A's in an existing thread.

Comment: it helps alot.right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
cat test.csv
17,"abc","Testurteil "sehr gut"","08/15"
99,"xyz","Testurteil "vernichtend"","4711"
```

Print out all fields of all lines (just for verification):

```
awk -F, '{print $0}' test.csv
17,"abc","Testurteil "sehr gut"","08/15"
99,"xyz","Testurteil "vernichtend"","4711"
```

The awk command line option "-F" allows you to set a different field separator than the standard blank.

Print out only your "special field", i.e., field number 3 of all lines:

```
awk -F, '{print $3}' test.csv
"Testurteil "sehr gut""
"Testurteil "vernichtend""
```

Maybe some comment for better readability (or export into a Key:Value store):

```
awk -F, '{print "Line" FNR ":field3 " $3}' test.csv 
Line1:field3 "Testurteil "sehr gut""
Line2:field3 "Testurteil "vernichtend""
```

Use more fields of your CSV file:

```
awk -F, '{print "Line number " FNR ": " $3 " for product "$1}' test.csv
Line number 1: "Testurteil "sehr gut"" for product 17
Line number 2: "Testurteil "vernichtend"" for product 99
```